# Not getting into Flotsam anymore

Tags: the-witcher-2

I was playing the Witcher 2 today, eagerly and interested in what the new patch has brought us, but I can not get into Flotsam anymore. Every time I enter the city, I get a cut scene of a guard saying: "Kill the bastard", followed by three arrows piercing through my body, resulting into a displeasing death.

I had the cut scene before (in Patch 2.0) but I could bribe the guards. As for now, I have no possibility to do anything, except watching myself die. I have accidentally killed a civilian near Flotsam, and I think that's why the guards are on my back again.

I wonder if someone knows how to bypass this cut-scene-o'-death and the guards, or how to modify or adjust something in the savefile or somewhere else, so that I am not a notorious butcher anymore, but a peaceful Witcher once again.

Comment: I'd try an earlier savegame if it is possible, I remember that cutscene when I'd refused to bribe the guards.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, [consensus](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/shot_dead_when_entering_flotsam_for_the_first_time) [seems](http://en.thewitcher.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24240-flotsam-wanted-for-crime/) [to be](http://en.thewitcher.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24431-flotsam-guards-bribe-bugged/) that this is a bug, even those that have not killed civilians cannot get into Flotsam.

Are you being asked for the 200 orens? If you are I'd recommend [hacking in](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB451GB451&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flotsam+guards#pq=flotsam+guards&hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=19&gs_id=22&xhr=t&q=witcher+2+money+cheat&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB451GB451&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=witcher+cheat+money&aq=0b&aqi=g-b3&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=222940e47befd69f&biw=1420&bih=651) 200 orens and paying them for now.

Comment: Already had to pay 200 orens. This is the second time, and they do not allow me to pay a fine this time, unfortunately. I will wait for a patch then, because I find the option of an earlier save not comfortable

Comment: @Wimpey Judging from other people's experiences, I don't think that would help you anyway.